# VirtualBox Guest Ubuntu 16.04 does dnot get DHCP IP when started on a Windows 10 host

Tags: windows-10, networking, virtualbox, hibernate, ubuntu-16.04

I have a VirtualBox VM Ubuntu 16.04 guest running on Window 10 Host

Problem: When I **resume** from **hibernation** on Windows 10 and then start the Ubuntu VM the guest OS does not get an IP. Using ethtool the interface is visible with link detected:yes, 1000Mb/s, Full and Autoneg ON.
Now keeping the VM in this state, if on the Windows 10 Host, I **disable** and **enable** the Windows **Wifi adapter** the VM then gets the IP.

Right now I just use a small bat file which needs to be run in administrator mode to perform the above operation.

This only happens if I resume Windows from hibernation.
Could this be a VirtualBox issue?

Comment: It probably cannot withstand the host hibernation (which essentially turns the computer OFF). Turn Hibernation OFF and set up Suspend to work. Suspend the computer and then see if the Guest machine keeps internet.  It does for me (VMware Workstation).

Comment: Yup Suspend solved the problem, Thanks.

Comment: I posted a solution and hopefully you will find it helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual Box while running probably cannot withstand the host hibernation (which essentially turns the computer OFF).

Turn Hibernation OFF and set up Suspend to work. Suspend the computer and then see if the Guest machine keeps internet.

This works for me (VMware Workstation)